# how to have a div with two images in any of 9 possible positions

Tags: html, css

I've racked my brain and tried everything I've read online but can't figure it 
out how to do this in HTML 4 and CSS 2.1 (for use in SharePoint 2010).

I've got a div of known height and width with two images of unknown height and width. We can assume the images are smaller then the div. I want to be able to position the two images in one of these locations:

- top left
- top middle
- top right
- center left
- center middle
- center right
- bottom left
- bottom middle
- bottom right

Each of the two images can be in a different location.

Any ideas/help?

```
<div style="width: 500px; height: 500px">
    <img src="..." />
    <img src="..." />
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd just make 6 classes to describe all the positions, then apply 2 to each image.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g7hydky2/)

```
.left {
    left: 0;
}
.center {
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.right {
    right: 0;
}
.top {
    top: 0;
}
.middle {
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
}
.bottom {
    bottom: 0;
}

<img class="left middle" />
```

Comment: This is brilliant! Thank you so much. It works for img tags. Anyway to get it to work for text elements like <i>, <div>, <span>?

Comment: Just make sure whatever element you choose, you give it `block` or `inline-block` display property so you can set its width.

Comment: What if I don't know the width? Like I won't know the width of the img or the span I want to position.