# position img|span|div of unknown dimensions in any of 9 possible positions within a div of unknown dimensions using pure CSS

Tags: html, css

I've asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30340103/how-to-have-a-div-with-two-images-in-any-of-9-possible-positions) and tried to modify it's answer for this but I'm not sure what to do.

I have a `div` of unknown dimensions and I need to place an `img`, `span`, or `div` in one of 9 positions within it.

- top left
- top middle
- top right
- center left
- center middle
- center right
- bottom left
- bottom middle
- bottom right

The question from above works for images but not with anything of unknown dimensions.

I've tried various combinations but cannot figure it out. http://jsfiddle.net/g7hydky2/3/ is what I'm working with.

The only thing I can think of is using `display: table` and `display: table-cell` on the outer and inner elements because then I can fully use `vertical-align` and `text-align`. However, this seems like a bad hack and I feel like there has to be a better way.

Also, I need this to work on IE 8...

Comment: @Paulie_D: I want to be able to place an element in a div and position it any one of those 9 positions. Like in the fiddle I want each of those spans to be placed in the appropriate position.

Answer (score 0):

Solved with `flexbox`,

Acknowledging this article - [**Getting Dicey with Flexbox**](http://davidwalsh.name/flexbox-dice)

```
.pip {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: black;
}
.one {
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
.two {
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
.three {
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
.four {
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
}
.five {
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.six {
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
}
.seven {
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
.eight {
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
.nine {
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}
.dice {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-radius: 15px;
  display: inline-flex;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 10px;
}
.pip {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: black;
}
.one {
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
.two {
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
.three {
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
.four {
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
}
.five {
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.six {
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
}
.seven {
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
.eight {
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
.nine {
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="dice one">
  <div class="pip"></div>
</div>
<div class="dice two">
  <div class="pip"></div>
</div>
<div class="dice three">
  <div class="pip"></div>
</div>
<div class="dice four">
  <div class="pip"></div>
</div>
<div class="dice five">
  <div class="pip"></div>
</div>
<div class="dice six">
  <div class="pip"></div>
</div>
<div class="dice seven">
  <div class="pip"></div>
</div>
<div class="dice eight">
  <div class="pip"></div>
</div>
<div class="dice nine">
  <div class="pip"></div>
</div>
```

---

For absolute certainty {pun intended} and older browswer support use positioning:  [**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/zGWYvR)

Comment: But what if I do not know the size of pip and dice?

Comment: Then you'll need javascript. If you don't know the size of the pip then there is no property supported by IE8 (that I'm aware of) that can help.

Comment: IE9 you could use transforms.